# Hide votes for self-answered by community wiki questions for a few hours

Tags: discussion, down-votes, community-wiki, self-answer

**Don't start reading this with a pre-conceived idea**. *I know similar topics have been discussed before*.

You want to share some piece of knowledge you've been searching for. You finally took the time to look it up; you tested it, and it works; you're a generous spirit, and you want to share it with the world. You take the time to write up the whole thing – as a community wiki answer, no less. Seconds after you post the whole write-up (question + answer), another user decides to downvote the question for some reason. No comment, no explanation, no nothing – just one singular downvote.

The next five users who see the question also see the "-1", so they think there must be something wrong with either the question or the answer – they neither upvote, nor downvote. The next five users do the same. The next five, the same – and so on, until someone breaks the chain.

But there is no chain. There is only a single downvote, cast by that singular first user who decided for some reason to downvote at first sight. The "chain" is just the accident of having a negative person notice the thing first – there could also be a positive "chain" if the accident happened the other way around.

I looked up similar conversations related to hiding votes for questions or answers, and I understand why it's important to give people feedback soon after they post either a question or an answer. Self-answered questions, however – and especially community wiki self-answered questions –, I think people are really making a free effort (both as in freedom, and as in beer) to offer their knowledge to the world. These people don't care about reputation points by definition, or else they wouldn't choose to post a community wiki answer.

If you think that maybe their question/answer content is genuinely crap, there are two separate counter-arguments to that:

- if the whole thing is just garbage, it will end up being downvoted so badly that it gets naturally kicked out – I'm only proposing temporarily hiding the vote count, not ignoring it;
- if only the wording is crap, the content might still be valuable – since we're talking about a community wiki answer, there's still hope someone will rewrite the answer. But if not, see above.

Comment: I see your POV, but I also don't think that there should necessarily be an exemption for self answers from the normal curation methods, which includes seeing a post's score. Is there evidence to suggest that self-answers get downvoted disproportionately?

Comment: Presumably this was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/q/64467830/3001761? As I understand it, the same guidelines apply for self-answered questions as any other.

Comment: @zcoop98 I see things the other way around. I think people are (too) easy to influence by metrics – we tend to follow the vlogger with the most viewers, or listen to the podcast with the most listeners. A true meritocratic system shouldn't even conceive of displaying metrics – what's good is intrinsically good, there's no need to show the number of viewers, listeners, or upvotes.

Having said that, I understand why it's important to show upvotes on StackExchange – and I why it's generally useful for the entire community to show them in real time. The point is, I see THAT as the exception.

Comment: @jonrsharpe true, that question was the trigger for this post. My proposed solution above was inspired by reddit's policy, at least on some subreddits, to hide the votes for a while after the initial post.

Comment: Maybe try to ask at SO Meta how your question and answer could be improved, there are the experts about the topic you're addressing. Also your question just has a single downvote for now, and ATM was written less than a day ago. I wouldn't expect that many people have seen it so far (only 27 views now) and found it useful. Just be patient.

Comment: In my opinion self-answers should be treated like any other answer. What if it gives potentially harmful advice? It would be bad if we wouldn't be able to downvote immediately.

Comment: @BogdanStăncescu Note that your proposed "question" is not even a question - a very strong hint is that there is not a single question mark in there. So I am surprised it hasn't been closed hours ago.

Comment: @piet.t I took the liberty of helping out on that front: I deleted the "un-question" myself so we can focus on the topic at hand instead of working on theories of mind attempting to address my motivation.

Comment: There's no statistics, just claimed personal experience, and no link to examples. You've not explained why only Wiki'd and self-answered questions should be affected and/or not every one, or why the feedback should also be hidden for the author. --- You've identified a concern (a vote, and then trending) without proof and sought to punish everyone rather than propose that the offenders (trend starters and followers) should be identified similar to the [tag:serial-voting] algorithm, while not waiting for the [downvote survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355416/282094) to complete.

Comment: @Rob, whoa, quite a lot of accusations for such a restricted medium, wonderful concision! I'm afraid there's been a misunderstanding, however – I never proposed hiding the feedback from the author, I never proposed punishing anyone (punish?! really?! where'd you get that from?!), and I wasn't aware of the survey; even now, I can't find a link where I could actually take the survey, I can only find discussions about it. At any rate, I don't find the community conductive to reaching any consensus beyond status quo in this matter – everyone just explained the various ways in which I'm wrong.

Comment: Bogdan, you have 3+/16- votes, without my vote. You can choose to accept the feedback and improve your question ***or*** you are allowed to see how your accusations hold out. Currently your idea, not you, needs some refinement. Whether it's a case of everyone being wrong or just a few people this week is yet to come.

Answer (score 10):

Curation does not deserve a delay, even for self-answered questions.  If the content is actually good, then the positive votes will outweigh the negative votes.  While I won't disagree with the sentiment that *some* votes appear to be cargo cult-like in that someone downvotes because someone else downvotes, it has been proven time and time again that good content will always be scored positively.

Comment: No. It has been proven time and time again that good content will always be scored positively in the end (statistically). You have not, however, shown that good content is always scored positively. Can you honestly argue that's the case? Can you honestly argue that every single user will cast a positive vote for valuable content?

Comment: @BogdanStăncescu Those users which will find your Q&A pair useful for solving the same problem they are researching, will upvote for sure. It just takes time. If it's a niche problem, it may take even more time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as I hinted in the OP, I don't care about reputation points – I don't even care if that question gets deleted altogether. My issue was setting up my Node environment, and I did that. Everything after that was sharing – on StackOverflow, the solution to that, and here, the solution to what I've seen a problem there. I took the time to write up both there and here because StackOverflow helped me tremendously throughout the years – I have no ulterior motive, and no vanity thing going on.

Comment: @BogdanStăncescu Did I imply anything about your motivation here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought you did – it seemed like you were attempting to appease my "need for justice" by providing the consolation of "future justice". I won't revisit those topics.

Comment: @BogdanStăncescu Nothing to do with _"justice"_ at all. I just tried to explain that good content will be well received over time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you for explaining that, but it was a premise I had taken for granted without faltering ever since my first answer above. The issue probably lies with me, for failing to clarify that in the first place.