# Is there a bias against using the "answer your own question" feature?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, self-answer, bias

I had a question.  As I was researching it while drafting it, I found more and more relevant information that I incorporated into my question.  It came to the point where it felt like I was answering my own question inside the question -- so, instead, I cut out all the "extra" stuff and put it into an answer using the "answer your own question" feature.

Within moments of publishing my paired Question and Answer, both had received 1 downvote.  There *may* have been time for someone to have read the question, but there's no way they had been able to read the answer.

Mere minutes later (maybe 5), the Question and Answer both had 3 downvotes each.

I will admit to becoming severely irritated.

Now, I can accept that the community might not have agreed with my answer and might downvote it because of that, but the question itself was not unreasonable.  It sure seemed like both the question and answer were being downvoted simply because I had answered my own question.

If this was a one-off, I might dismiss it, but the only other time I have ever received lots of downvotes for a question and/or an answer was the other time when I had immediately answered my own question.

I know that the *system* accepts answering your own question -- and even promotes it with one or more badges -- but it sure feels like the community may be against it.

Is there such a bias?

I suggest that those who have access to the data investigate to see if this is a trend.  If it is, maybe the "Answer your own question" and related badges should be removed, or maybe something should be done to change users' behavior.

---

Related: [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

---

FOLLOW-UP EDIT

To be clear, I'm not asking if my specific questions or answers merited the downvotes they received.  They might have, or they might not.  However, I noticed the pattern in my limited experience that my immediately self-answered questions (and those answers) provoked a significant knee-jerk negative response.

My question was intended to see if this observation was unique to me, or if others had experienced it, or if others had access to a broader data set that might show it was a trend.

Regardless, I know that I myself have had a negative experience twice now.  It has made me less happy to participate, and I don't plan to ever immediately answer my own question again.  I'm wondering if the format should be changed to prevent others from experiencing this bad feeling in the future.

Maybe questioners should be prevented from answering their own questions for a certain period of time.  Or maybe the questioners' and/or answerers' identities (and reputations and badges) should be masked for a certain duration.  Or maybe there's a better idea out there...

Comment: Yes, there is. personally I find it annoying to see a question posted that doesn't need any problem to be solved. *Self answered questions are just that.* It's hard for me to disconnect from the idea that you're just posting it to earn rep, and not for the purpose of building a better knowledge base.

Comment: Related: [Is it typical for self-answered questions to be downvoted?](/q/362965/289905).

Comment: This question appears to be motivated by [Can a trickery cleric's illusory duplicate make opportunity attacks?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/184819) (not hard to find in your network profile). I have no expertise in this topic whatsoever, so I can’t really comment on why you may have received these downvotes.

Comment: Some self-answered questions reach Hot Network Question status and get 20+ upvotes. It doesn't that happen that often, but it does happen. So a 'selfie' doesn't automatically guarantee downvotes at all.

Comment: a few questions breaking the mold doesn't necessarily prove there isn't some level of bias against them

Comment: I think that you should make this question on the corresponding per-site meta as the each community might have their own "bias", actually on some sites the behavior might not be the same across tags of one site.

Comment: @Rubén I'm a relative newbie, and this is the only meta site I'm aware of.  How would I locate the "per-site meta"?

Comment: My answer doesn't change with your edit.  If a question or answer deserves to be downvoted due to its lack of clarity or usefulness, then it's eligible to be downvoted. That's about the best anyone can say without getting into the nuances of how other sites are run.

Comment: @gto prepend `meta.` to the site uri i.e. `meta.stackoverflow.com`, `meta.rpg.stackexchange.com`. The UI has several links to the per-site meta but sometimes they are not very obvious.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you.  Should I delete the question here?  There's that warning about using the privilege to ask questions if you delete them, but the response here has been... contentious.

Comment: You will not be able to delete it by your own as the question already has answers with a positive score ---> https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/289691

Comment: Anecdotal evidence, but my 3 self-Q&As got fairly positive reception on Gaming.SE: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/205487/80914), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/210250/80914), [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/211092/80914)

Comment: Kevin B doesn't realize that the purpose of answering your own question helps this site when the solution was hard to find; you found it and are sharing it.. Not everyone is out to burnish their 'rep'..

Answer (score 15):

This can't be comprehensively answered because the premise of not deserving downvotes tacitly *assumes* that the question and answer pair were useful.  Without seeing the Q&A pair and without experts on that site weighing in, then we're just left guessing.

Fundamentally speaking, in a broad sense, this reinforces the notion that every question and answer is still subject to the community's sense of quality, topicality and usefulness, whether it's self-answered or not.

If a question is poor or unclear, then it could merit a downvote.  If the answer is not useful, incomplete or incoherent, then it could merit a downvote.

Answer (score 13):

Whether or not there are biases, it's not reflected in the votes; which is the premise of your question.

- SEDE - Glorfindel's Query: "[Downvotes on self-answered questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1394657/downvotes-on-self-answered-questions)":

|  | Total | Average Score | Average # of DVs | % Downvoted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Questions | 21165893 | 2.14 | 0.23 | 14 |
| Self-Answered | 2246623 | 2.2 | 0.17 | 11 |

- SEDE - Glorfindel's Query, [zcoop98](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/34494) edited: "[Downvotes on self-answered questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1394680/downvotes-on-self-answered-questions)":

|  | Total | Average Score | Average # of DVs | % Downvoted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Questions | 67201740 | 1.97 | 0.3 | 16 |
| Self-Answered | 2246623 | 2.2 | 0.17 | 11 |

As you can see, on Stack Overflow self-answered questions get slightly more upvotes and slightly fewer downvotes; the opposite of what you suggest in your question. It ***is*** still possible for there to be a bias, we'd need a double blind test to prove that, but if there were a bias the user still comes out slightly ahead; a result one would not expect if there were prejudice against them.

I chose to run the query on Stack Overflow since there's more data, resulting in a bigger pool, but even that choice *could* reflect a bias; or highlight one, some sites might dislike self answers more than others.

One evidence of that is our Science Fiction and Fantasy site. When [zcoop98's query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1394680/downvotes-on-self-answered-questions) is run there we maintain a slightly higher score, but the number of downvotes is reversed and this time slightly increased:

|  | Total | Average Score | Average # of DVs | % Downvoted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Questions | 218571 | 7.9 | 0.76 | 33 |
| Self-Answered | 2448 | 10.82 | 0.85 | 36 |

Here another interesting query by [MBraedley](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/4373) (edited by anonymous), back at Stack Overflow: "[Self answered questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1372056/self-answered-questions)":

[image: MBraedley's Query]

As you can see, on the upper end the answer gets even more votes than the question; while on the lower end questions with negative votes don't get their answers blasted down along with their mildly downvoted question.

I suggest that your bias caused by having your self-answers downvoted isn't reflected in the data as the experience of other users; perhaps they had their own bias to try harder and avoid the expected backlash that was (apparently) never unleashed.

Data supports questions and answers, and users are supposed to support good questions and answers; and that's supported by the data - YMMV, certain exceptions may apply.

Comment: I appreciate the data-based response.  Is there a way to parse this data versus the time to answer the question?  That is, is there a way to see if the votes cast within minutes of publishing self-answered questions are more negative than the votes cast in the long run?

Comment: @gto another thing to look at is immediately self answered vs delayed self answers. The former means OP had both to hand. The latter could mean it was solved over time with research.

Comment: @gto unfortunately, this can't be done anymore with SEDE: " time data is purposefully removed to protect user privacy". At max, you can tell that the votes came on the same day, but that's it.

Comment: @OlegValter  That may still add some value.  If the votes cast on the same day as publishing are more negative for self-answered questions than for others as compared to the overall eventual vote, that will support the "knee-jerk" response I observed anecdotally.

Comment: @gto - just mentioning so as you don't get your hopes up about the "see if the votes cast within minutes of publishing" part. I agree that the daily data may be useful, though

Comment: @gto, in reference to [your *new* theory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364138/is-there-a-bias-against-using-the-answer-your-own-question-feature/364150?noredirect=1#comment1215254_364150): people often complain about *initial* DVs because it's thought to provoke a following of further downvotes; that's somewhat harder to disprove if those initial votes correctly reflect the value of the post - similarly the reverse is also applicable. But, that upsets your new question's theory, or proposition, in that it's not a "knee jerk" but a landslide or slippery slope; like these theories.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the latter could also mean the person posting the self answer *wanted* it too look like it was done over time with research.

Comment: Sure - but that means they did a very good job at it :D

Comment: eh, i think this generally will hold true in the long-term, both due to deletion and the imbalance of upvotes vs downvotes. given all the different scenarios that exist, I don't think SEDE is really a great way of looking at this. you *could* compare the overall outcomes of all questions ot the overall outcome of self answered... but... again, when we're looking at initial reaction... sede will generally leave off the very signal we're looking for.

Comment: @Rob It's not a new theory; it's just a level of detail I didn't get into.  The first time this happened, the question got the immediate downvotes and then held in that state for a long time, but eventually it did turn around after someone else thought highly enough of it to offer a bounty.  I suspect the knee-jerk bias happens immediately, but then may fade over time (because others provide answers, and time passing makes it less obvious that an answer was published simultaneously).  If so, the question might then stand on its own merits.  But not all questions will get this 2nd chance.

Comment: @gto, once answers are provided any new thoughts must not invalidate any of the existing answers, if you have a new question you are welcome to write a new question; even self answer these. Perhaps these related questions will help more than our answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350585/how-do-sites-moderate-self-answered-questions?answertab=votes#tab-top  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/282094    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355679/282094 - etc.

Comment: @Rob  I'm not "invalidating" any answers.  I'm simply stating that the possible bias may be transient, so the data-based answer here should take an additional step and examine this possibility, which I'm led to believe is feasible.

Comment: @gto, as [explained yesterday by Oleg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364138/is-there-a-bias-against-using-the-answer-your-own-question-feature#comment1215253_364150) (in the 3rd comment above), that's [no longer possible](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1150488/score-history-graph-of-a-post?PostId=6581949); you only get the daily result, not any finer resolution. See [the result, and graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbHT3.jpg). Whichever question you look at will only provide the daily result, we don't have permission to "take an additional step".

Comment: @Rob And, as I said in my reply to Oleg, comparing Day 1, 2, 3, etc. versus the long-term results would be enough resolution to address the question.

Comment: gto, that's not what's been discussed.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is a bias against self answers, in one way or another. They tend to be held to a higher standard for various reasons. However, I think they serve a necessary purpose and the site would be worse off without the feature.

1. Immediately self answered questions don't have the benefit of having
   a user that is waiting for an answer to justify their existence.
2. The question itself is often either bare, lacking the necessary information to adequately answer, or the question is so detailed that it effectively answers itself before you reach the answer. It's hard to write a question when you know all the details needed to reach the answer.

If the option didn't exist people would simply post their answer after asking, potentially frustrating answerers by effectively spinning their wheels "helping" someone who doesn't need help.

Comment: I don't think you've demonstrated that there *is* a bias; you're just stoking the flames of there *might* be a bias, which (for better or worse) only reinforces the misconception of the OP, which is...not desirable.

Comment: That's true. I'm not sure what bias would look like if not people thinking self answers are useless, like myself. but there's no real way to prove that exists on any meaningful level without something much bigger than a meta question.